# SVG Importer giving errror telling me to move settings to resource folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg

I'm trying to import the SVG importer into my project, but I keep getting an error, here is the error:

```
Cannot Load SVG Importer Settings! Please Move SVG Importer Settings in to Resource folder.
```

I have the SVG Importer Settings in a resources folder so i don't know what is wrong.

[image: Resources folder]

[image: Resources folder 2]

That is what my resources folder looks like ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the **.asset** file containing the settings into the *Resources* folder, not the **.cs** file as it looks like you've done now. Maybe you need to create an `SVGImporterSettings` asset first, using the *Create* right-click menu.

Comment: That works now, it isn't giving me that error, but i can't import SVG's still, they don't show up when I go `Assets -> Import New Asset`. I can type the start of the file name it shows up in `File Name`, selecting that I press import but it doesn't let me import it, the button does nothing.

Edit:
I also get an error that says it failed to load svgImporterSettings.asset.